# Qt/C++ how to wait a slot when signal emitted

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt5, signals-slots

I have developed an app in Qt/C++, I have used signal/slot mechanism to interact between 2 threads. the first thread run the UI/TreeWidget and the second one run the framework

I got an issue on one action.

In the UI side, before starting my action, I'm connect signal/slot between UI and framework such as below in the treewidget.cpp

```
connect(&m_Framework, &Framework::RequestIfNameExist, this, &TreeWidget::RequestIfNameExist);
connect(this, &TreeWidget::SendAnswerIfNameExist, &m_Framework, &Framework::NotifIfNameExist);
```

The framework, start and send the RequestIfNameExist:

```
emit RequestIfNameExist(tmpname, item, fileInfo.isDir());

while(WaitingResponse == false){
    usleep(200);
}
```

I have added a loop because I need to wait the feedback. Strange things is that in the treewidget.cpp, I never enter in

```
void TreeWidget::RequestIfNameExist(QString name, TreeWidgetItem *parent, bool isFolder) {
#ifdef PULS_LOG
    QLOG_INFO() << "[TreeWidget] [RequestIfNameExist] ";
#endif
    emit SendAnswerIfNameExist(isNameExist(name, parent), isFolder);
}
```

I never access to RequestIfNameExist in the TreeWidget but the signal is emitted.

I have also put a while loop in the framework to wait the feedback from TreeWidget

```
void Framework::NotifIfNameExist(QTreeWidgetItem *item, bool isFolder){

    if(item != NULL)
        item->isFolder = isFolder;

    WaitingResponse = true;

}
```

Any idea why the signal emitted by framework never arrived on the treewidget ? is it coming from the while ??

Is there a way to not use while such as a "wait event" + timeout

Thanks

Comment: The Framework thread is running the while loop, so it won't be able to execute `NotifIfNameExist`.  It is odd to have the Framework query a UI element loke Treewidget. Usually the UI queries a backend like framework to get the data and UI states.

Comment: I think you want to to `connect` the signals and slots in your signal class for each signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought is that having either thread block until an operation in the other thread completes is a poor design -- it partially defeats the purpose of having multiple threads, which is to allow multiple operations to run in parallel.  It's also liable to result in deadlocks if you're not careful (e.g. if both threads decide to emit-and-wait at approximately the same time!)

A better design would have the initiating method do the `emit RequestIfNameExit` and then return immediately, so that the initiating thread's event loop can continue running as usual during the operation.  Then, when the other thread has done its work, it responds by emitting its own response-signal, causing the appropriate/connected slot-method in the first thread to be called, at which point the results are handled back in the first thread.

That said, if you insist on wanting to block the execution of the signal-emitting thread inside a method, until the other thread has finished executing the associated slot-method, you can get that behavior by setting the signal/slot connection's type to be [Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) (the connection type can be specified via an optional extra argument to [connect()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect)).  If you do that, then you emit call won't return until the slot-method (in the other thread) has finished executing.  Given that, you can get the results from the other thread by passing a pointer to a data object as one of the arguments in the signal/slot method signature, and having the other thread populate that data object as necessary.  When the emit returns you can just examine the contents of that data object to see the results.

Comment: There are some situations where this design is perfectly reasonable. For example, in the case of only two threads, the main/UI thread and one worker thread, the worker thread may encounter an exception or issue such as failing to copy a file and the designer wishes to ask the user if they want to try again or skip it if that happens. In this situation the worker thread cannot continue until it knows the answer and it must be stopped since the QMessageBox can only be executed on the main thread.

Comment: @oblivioncth having the worker thread block until it gets a response from the GUI thread introduces a potential deadlock, since there will also be times (e.g. when the user quits the app) when the GUI will be blocking (in `join()`) until the worker thread goes away.  When you have thread A waiting for thread B to do something, and thread B simultaneously waiting for thread A to do something else, you've got a deadlock.

Comment: Sure, that certainty is possible and something that would need to be watched out for. Probably a more likely issue on apps with more complex UIs that would allow for such a situation to arise. I suppose it would ultimately be safer to implement a "response" slot in the worker thread, even though it would require some restructuring of functions in said thread.

Comment: It can happen on any app that allows the user to quit while the worker thread is running.